# How widespread is the use of "hais" instead of the correct "habeis"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, dialectos

After living in Andalucia, Spain, for a number of years I realised my use of "hais" for the second person informal plural (*vosotros*) of *haber* instead of "habeis" is incorrect. I don't know where I picked it up. Googling shows me that it is used in some isolated areas of Spain. Is it used in Latin America? Is it used only by country bumpkins or is it recognized as acceptable slang?

Answer (score 4):

It is not standard Spanish and I've likewise never heard it.

That said, many regions of Spain spoke (and/or speak) languages other than Castilian and, as a result, their Castilian can be sometimes strongly influenced by those.  Note their conjugations of *haber/haver*:

```
         Language |    Conjugation    |  Note
------------------+-------------------+--------------- --- -- -  -   - 
         Asturian |       vós habéis  |
        Aragonese |  busatros ez      |
Catalan/Valencian | vosaltres heu     | also, less commonly, “haveu”
         Galician |       vós havedes |
          Leonese | vosoutros heis    | possibly “hais” in modern times
        Mirandese |       vós heis    |
       Portuguese |       vós havéis  | also, less commonly, “heis”
```

<sup>Sources (for less common languages): [Mirandese](http://mirandes.no.sapo.pt/co/co3.html#amostraverbirr), [Leonese](https://books.google.com/bookshttps://books.google.com/books?id=cgpZjYdf97YC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=verbos%20lleones&source=bl&ots=LTw2m5KQ-b&sig=SPpyQobcTw8AYIykk8dYRC5fzNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwB2oVChMIg72euK31xgIVBKA-Ch3A9w3l#v=onepage&q=verbos%20lleones&f=false), [Aragonese](http://www.unizar.es/unibersida/aragones/page38.htm).</sup>

So, it is certainly possible that you've heard it if the person is from León, Aragón, a Catalonian/Valencian-speaking region, or along the Portuguese border, who is not used to *haber* being regular for *vosotros*.  The E/A vowels can alternate a good bit from Castilian, especially with Leonese and Aragonese (and my Leonese source is from a century ago) so it's not inconceivable that a vowel swap could have changed *heis* -> *hais*, or it developed as regularized irregular form based on *has* (or *han*, etc.) -> *hais*.

I doubt seriously the average Spanish speaker would hear *hais* as being *haber* for *vosotros*. Most likely, they'd probably hear it as a mispronunciation of *has*. If they did recognize it for whatever reason, though, their view of it will probably vary greatly by how they were familiarized with it, whether they speak one of the languages in question, etc.

In Latin America, I can't imagine it being used or recognized at all in *tuteante* (except as a mispronunciation of *has*). I believe the *voseante* regions generally have *has* ~ *habés* ~ *habé(i)*, so I doubt *hais* would be used or really understood by any of them, either.

So basically, don't use it, because even if people recognize it (unlikely), you won't be able to necessarily predict how they'll interpret it sociolinguistically.

Comment: I guess you meant *haveu* vs *heu* without final «s» for Catalan. Specially for the latter, as with an «s» it's the 2nd person singular of the lexical form of the verb, barely used unless it's bundled in the expression «heus aquí».

Comment: @guifa:- Ta for that, I suppose I was thinking along the lines of "ain't" for "isn't" or "hasn't": it's recognisable to most English speakers even if they don't use it, but it seems that "hais" would not be recognised.

Comment: Here's another example, from Leon: http://webs.ono.com/grulleros/habla.htm

Comment: @guillem yup, this is what I get for doing it on my phone flipping from conjugation tables in one tab and the editor for this site in another :-)

Comment: I have actually heard this use in the Aragonese countryside, but it is regarded as highly incorrect.

Comment: @Gorpik thus the predictive powers of comparative linguistics :-) (I've never been to Aragon but... totally guessed it'd be one of the places haha)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the talking speed, I think no one says "hais". My family birthplace in extremadura has some heavy influences of Leonese when speaking and I've never heard any "hais"

Answer (score 4):

I am not a linguist, but I am a user of the word "hais". I think its origin is related to the Leonese "heis". My family comes from Extremadura, a land with historical Leonese influence. But I was born in the Basque Country and I never realised the fact that "hais" is not the Spanish standard word until a teacher of Latin read my translation of "habḗtis".

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome! You seem to have created two different accounts with the same name. If this is the case, [this](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, interesting: it's nice to know it does exist in some places in Spain. I learned my everyday Spanish here in the Alpujarra, a region with many external influences and I think I picked up my use of "hais" here.

Answer (score 3):

Our Chilean colloquial *voseo* verbs (*estái, tenís, decís*) come from the archaic *voseo* forms, the same as those of "*vosotros*" (*estáis, tenéis, decís, sois, ibais, vierais*):

**Archaic *voseo* → Current Chilean *voseo***

- *vos cantáis → vos cantái / tú cantái*
- *vos queréis → vos querís / tú querís*
- *vos tenéis → vos tenís / tú tenís*
- *vos decís → vos decís / tú decís*
- *vos ibais → vos ibai / tú ibai*
- *vos vais → vos vai / tú vai*
- *vos sois → vos soi / tú soi*

<sub>(Using "*vos*" in Chile is considered excessively informal and, in some cases, offensive and even vulgar. It's always pronounced "*voh*".)</sub>

Following this logic, "*vos habéis*" would become "*vos habís*" / "*tú habís*", but this form is extremely rare. Instead, we use "*vos **hai**" / "tú **hai***":

> *¿Cómo **hai** estado?* (How have you been?)
>
> *¿**Hai** cachado que...?* (Have you noticed that...?)
>
> *Tú nunca **hai** hecho eso.* (You have never done that)
>
> *¿Qué te **hai** creído?* (Who do you think you are?)

**It's not incorrect, it's just colloquial**, like any other Chilean voseo verb (in fact, it would sound weird and snob if the *tuteo* form "*has*" were used in a colloquial context instead of "*hai*").

And since all "*-áis*" ending verbs became "*-ái*", our current "*hai*" should come from a hypothetical "***hais***":

***vos *hais → vos hai / tú hai***

But I'm not sure if the transition was *habéis→habís→hai* or *habéis→hais→hai*.
This is the only case where I can think of something related to an "*hais*" here in Latin America.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it used in Latin America?*

---

Nope.
In most of Latin America, the common form would be "han" to go with "ustedes" for the informal second person plural.

Answer (score 1):

I have lived in Sevilla (capital of Andalusia) for almost 28 years and I think I have never heard * *hais*, which is obviously incorrect and anyone with some basic education will stigmatize as vulgar.

Some poorly educated people do say * *habemos* instead of *hemos*. But I don't think people say * *hais*.

Comment: Just one quick exemplar:-  http://villafafila.net/habla/habla.htm

Comment: *habemos* is actually OK, but only for the expression habérselas. It's weird.

Comment: @guifa I guess if you’re going to have it out with somebody, it’s ok to sound archaic: [Solo es admisible hoy en la lengua culta el uso de la forma *habemos* como primera persona del plural del presente de indicativo de la expresión coloquial *habérselas* con una persona o cosa (‘enfrentarse a ella o tratar con ella a la fuerza’): *Ya sabéis con quién nos las habemos; Nos las habemos con un asesino despiadado.*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/habemos) They also give two cases where they don’t like it.